# How to mapping ports from a single public IP to multiple internal servers in Fortigate Firewall?

Tags: nat, pat

I have one public IP and I want to use it for 3 servers behind Fortigate Firewall, two for RDP and one for Mail server. I can NAT one public ip to one private local ip but I can not NAT to Multiple Private IPs with the same Port.

How to map ports with a single public IP to multiple internal servers?

Comment: Flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking". Could you try again to clearly state what you want to do? Besides: What did you do help yourself, what research have you done so far?

Comment: this is typically achieved with ExtPort A -> IntIP-a:IntportA, ExtPortB -> IntIP-B:InportB , the problem I'm also stuck on this issue having multiple external ports, natted to multiple internal servers on different ports

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not possible to forward same port to multiple internal servers over the same public ip. How should the Firewall know which server the request to forward to if requests are coming to the same ip,on the same port?

Your only option is to forward different ports on the firewall, to same ports on the internal servers (example only).

```
port-3389(Firewall public ip)---->port3389(Server1 private ip)
port-XXXX(Firewall public ip)---->port3389(Server2 private ip)
port-25(Firewall public ip)------>port25(Server3 private ip)
```

..etc.